# How to skip rows which contains more columns than number of header columns from csv file in spark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Eg:

Id,Name,Department

1,Smith,HR

2,John,IT,Comments

3,Steven,Sales

I need to ignore row number 2 here and read only first and last records.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to skip malformed records, you can use [`DROPMALFORMED` mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv-scala.collection.Seq-).

Example:

```
spark
 .read
 .option("header", true)
 .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
 .csv(path)
```